# matplotlib axes histogram patches

Tags: matplotlib, histogram, axes

How do you get the object from `ax.hist()` and then `setp` for the object.
Here is what I mean:

```
n,bins2,patches =
ax2.hist(arra,bins=18,weights=1./bias,normed=False,color='#d9d9db')
ax2.hist.setp(edgecolor='g')
```

Well, obviously this doesn't work! I am getting an error:

```
File "./bin_data.py", line 112, in <module>
    ax2.hist.setp(edgecolor='g')
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'setp'
```

Your help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What if you put `edgecolor='g'` in the first command itself. Also try using `ax2.setp(edgecolor='g') `

Comment: Hmmm, interesting! It worked, although I don't understand why it did! Does it mean that `ax.hist()`, somehow inherits the attributes of `patches`? Because if you do `n,bins,pathes = plt.hist()`, then you can do `plt.setp()` but you can't do it with `axes`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course to change the edgecolor you may directly supply it to the histogram function

```
n,bins2,patches = ax2.hist(..., facecolor='#d9d9db', edgecolor="g")
```

To answer the question: The object to set the color to is the third return of `hist`, which is a container of bars

```
n,bins2,patches = ax2.hist(..., color='#d9d9db')
plt.setp(patches, edgecolor="g")
```

Comment: Excellent! That worked and is a nice explanation. I am accepting this as the correct answer! Thank you!